# Google app engine's ndb: using id or key name?

Tags: google-app-engine

This is about Google App Engine's ndb. According to my observations, if I create an entity without providing any key, the entity will have an integer, starting with 1 and being incremental, in the `ID` field as shown in Datastore Viewer. However, if I create the entity by providing with a string as its id, the entity will have a string in the `Key Name` field. For example:

Model:

```
class Member(ndb.Model):
  ...
```

program:

```
member1 = Member()            # --> ID is 1, Key Name is None
member2 = Member(id='abc')    # --> ID is empty, Key Name is 'abc'
```

In addition, in the html file, if I use

```
<input ... name="id" value={{member1.key.id}} ... />
```

as a parameter to return to the server-side program (Python), none of the following two statements will work for member1:

```
Member.get_by_id(self.request.get('id'))
member1 = Member.get_by_id(int(self.request.get('id')))
```

However, the following html and program codes:

```
<input ... name="id" value={{member2.key.id}} ... />
member2 = Member.get_by_id(self.request.get('id'))
```

will work for member2.

There seems no problem for entities created by providing with string id's (i.e., member2). But the same doesn't work for member1. My questions: a) Are my observations correct? b) How do I fetch member1 using `get_by_id()`?

Comment: Have you fetched all Members and examined their keys so that you know 1.  that you have in fact written member1 and member2 ?
and

Comment: 2. what keys you have actually created

Answer (score 13, accepted):

a) Mostly correct, though you should be able to get `member1` through the second method you showed. Also can't verify that integer IDs always start at 1 and will always be incremental. I've seen mixed results in regards  to that.

b) `member1 = Member.get_by_id(int(self.request.get('id')))` should work

You could also try using `key.urlsafe()` so you dont have to worry about key id conversions:

`<input ... name="id" value={{member.key.urlsafe()}} ... />`

```
member_key = self.request.get('id')
member = ndb.Key(urlsafe=member_key).get()
```

Comment: Thanks for confirming some of my observations. After more experiments, I have the following conclusion. If an entity is created without id (e.g., `member1 = Member()`), then it's ID is an integer and can be fetched by `member1 = Member.get_by_id(int(self.request.get('id')))`. However, if an entity is created with an id (e.g., `member2 = Member(id='abc')`), then it's Key Name is 'abc', and it can be fetched by `member2 = Member.get_by_id(self.request.get('id'))`. Both of them uses the same template variables in HTML: `{{member1.key.id}} and {{member2.key.id}}`

Comment: Is it secure convert the long number from allocate_id to int? Or will it be posible to truncate the integer in the conversion?